# creating in-app settings for iPad applications

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, settings, in-app

I want to create in-app settings for my iPad application. There are different alerts for different groups, so the user can select which alerts he/she wants in the application. I am putting a custom button which will look like checkbox so when user will click it, it will be highlighted.

Can anyone tell me where can I store the settings, do I need to save settings in keychain or somewhere else? Is there any tutorial for doing that?

Comment: See my detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885997/using-plists-for-persistence-on-iphone/6886100#6886100

Comment: I've used NSUserDefaults for in-app settings as well as other small data storage. I think it would work very well for what you would need.

Answer (score 2):

I've found [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) very helpful for stuff like this. Basically you do this to store values:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:yourBool forKey:@"yourBoolKey"];
[defaults setInteger:yourInteger forKey:@"yourIntegerKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And to get values:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
yourBool= [defaults boolForKey:@"yourBoolKey"];
yourInteger= [defaults integerForKey:@"yourIntegerKey"];
```

To have default settings when the app first launches, you could just check a bool with the key `@"AppHasStoredSettings"` or something like that, which will be `NO` the first time, set your default settings, and then set it to `YES`.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing would probably be a plist, which, in reality is a structured XML file with keys and values, but Apple abstracts most of that for you pretty well with some nice settings tools. Here's a few things to peruse to get a handle on the idea:

- [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSUserDefaults)
- [User Defaults Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i)
- [Information about property list files](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i)

Luke put some helpful code, but look at these too for more examples and ways to use all the tools available.