# Storing user information on first use of iPad app

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios6

I am writing an app and would like to do the following: When the app is first used it prompts the user for a username given at the time of purchase. When entered this is then stored and cannot be changed.

I am unsure whether this is possible or if it is what method I should use to store it. I am right in thinking this is one for KeyChain?

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: If it's just one username then maybe a simple .plist would suffice.

Comment: Thank for your help. I am new to this. How would I write to the .plist?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885997/using-plists-for-persistence-on-iphone/6886100#6886100

Comment: Thanks - I'll have go at this. Can I check - once set it will be stored even when the app is closed, and not able to be changed from outside of the app?

Comment: Depending your security needs, just write the username to NSUserDefaults. No need to mess with plists for this. If security is an issue, then use the keychain.